# How to count the total number of black pieces on the board?

Tags: haskell

For haskell , is there a way to count the number of just black pieces if the board is given as below.

```
initialBoard =
 Board
 [ Just (Black, 2)
 , Nothing
 , Nothing
 , Nothing
 , Just (Black, 2)
 , Just (White, 5)
 , Nothing
 , Just (White, 3)
 , Nothing
 , Nothing
 , Nothing
 , Just (Black, 5)
 , Just (White, 5)
 , Nothing
 , Nothing
 , Nothing
 , Just (Black, 3)
 , Nothing
 , Just (Black, 5)
 , Nothing
 , Nothing
 , Nothing
 , Nothing
 , Just (White, 2)
 ]
```

I new to haskell, I am wondering whether haskell has a function like the for...in... loop in python to allows me check every item in the list.Thanks

Comment: While this probably isn’t the most useful for a beginner to Haskell, just for fun, using the [`lens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) library, you can express this very concisely as `lengthOf (_Just._1._Black)`.

Comment: `length [() | let Board xs = initialBoard, Just (Black, _) <- xs]`

Comment: @4castle or, similarly though perhaps closer to a common Python idiom, `sum [1 | let Board xs = initialBoard, Just (Black, _) <- xs]`

Comment: I'm guessing `sum [n | let Board xs = initialBoard, Just (Black, n) <- xs]` would be closer to what's wanted - that looks like the starting position on a backgammon board, in which case the second part of the tuple would be the number of pieces on a given point

Answer (score 3):

Use `filter` to remove all the `Nothing` and `Just (White, _)` values, then count what is left.

```
isBlack :: Maybe (Color, Int) -> Bool
isBlack (Just (Black, _)) = True
isBlack _ = False

countBlacks :: Board -> Int
countBlacks = length . filter isBlack
```

A somewhat longer, but "obvious", one-line definition might be

```
import Data.Maybe (isJust, fromJust)

-- 1. Get rid of Nothings
-- 2. Extract the tuples from the Just values
-- 3. Extract the colors from the tuples
-- 4. Get rid of the Whites
-- 5. Count what's left.
countBlacks = length . filter (== Black) . map fst . map fromJust . filter isJust
```

or

```
countBlacks = length . filter (== Black) . map (fst . fromJust) . filter isJust
```

or

```
countBlacks = length . filter ((== Black) . fst . fromJust) . filter isJust
```

making use of the identities

- `map f . map g == map (f . g)`
- `filter f . map g == filter (f . g)`

Note that `fromJust` should be used with caution; `fromJust Nothing` is not defined and will raise an error. Here, it is safe because `filter isJust` guarantees that the values `fromJust` will be applied to are `Just` values.

A safer replacement is the `maybe` function, which provides a default value given a `Nothing`. (You can think of `fromJust` as being implement as `maybe undefined id`.)

```
countBlacks = length . filter (maybe False f)
  where f (Black, _) = True
        f _ = False
```

since `maybe False f Nothing` evaluates to `False`.

Comment: To avoid the partial function: `map fromJust . filter isJust` = `catMaybes` from `Data.Maybe`.

Answer (score 3):

chepner suggested, more or less, that you filter for `Just` then for `Black`.

I'm suggesting an alternative where you convert your list `[Maybe (Color,Int)]` into a `[Color]` that has the same answer then filter and count:

```
countBlacks = length . filter (== Black) . map (maybe White fst)
                         ^                       ^
                         |                        -- Just (x, _) ~> x
                         |                        -- Nothing     ~> White
                         --- list ~> [Black, Black ... Black]
```

As an alternative, you could convert to `[Int]` of ones or zeros representing black or white and sum:

```
 countBlacks = sum . map (maybe 0 (fromEnum . (== Black) . fst))
```

Answer (score 3):

Some setup to make this compile:

```
data Color = Black | White deriving Eq

newtype Board = Board [Maybe (Color, Int)]
```

Solve one small piece at a time; there is no valor in tackling a problem in a single step. Keep finding ways to transform the data you have, discarding information until you're left with only what you want.

Perhaps start with a function that just gets the pieces that are on the board, thus discarding the information about their location which we don't care about:

```
import Data.Maybe (catMaybes)

-- | Produce a list of all the pieces on a board.
boardPieces :: Board -> [(Color, Int)]
boardPieces (Board xs) = catMaybes xs
```

We're only interested in pieces of one color, so how about a function that takes a list of pieces and returns only the piece types for that color -- thus discarding information about the pieces of the other color we don't care about.

```
-- | Given a list of pieces with colors, produce a list
-- that only contains the pieces for a particular color.
filterByColor :: Color -> [(Color, Int)] -> [Int]
filterByColor x = filter (\(y, i) -> x == y)
```

To figure out the number of black pieces on a board, then, we can

1. Get the list of pieces on the board
2. Filter that list by color
3. Take the length of that list

```
-- | The number of black pieces on the board.
numBlacks :: Board -> Int
numBlacks = length . filterByColor Black . boardPieces
```

Test:

```
λ> numBlacks initialBoard
5
```